# Stop DataLogger if there is no movement

Tags: android, movesense

Movesense have small memory. With continuous recording from two axes, the memory is full after 13 minutes. There is an idea to stop logging when Movesense does not move (extremely small move) and to recover data after receiving by Timestamp.

Implemented logging of two axes and start-stop recording by a command from Android. Need a help to implement a start-stop recording on a specific condition inside the Movesense, when Android is disconnected from the sensor.

```
        DataLoggerConfig.DataEntry[] entries = {
                new DataLoggerConfig.DataEntry("/Meas/Acc/13"),
                new DataLoggerConfig.DataEntry("/Meas/Gyro/13")
        };
        DataLoggerConfig config = new DataLoggerConfig(new DataLoggerConfig.Config(new DataLoggerConfig.DataEntries(entries)));
        String jsonConfig = new Gson().toJson(config,DataLoggerConfig.class);
        getMDS().put(configUri, jsonConfig, new MdsResponseListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(String data) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(MdsException e) {
            }
        });
```

On Movesense sensor:

```
OPTIONAL_CORE_MODULE(DataLogger, true)
OPTIONAL_CORE_MODULE(Logbook, true)
```

Comment: Have you tried making a custom service in the firmware? Then you should be able to do this quite easily. The most tricky part will be to set up the logbook and datalogger internally on the sensor.

Comment: Created custom service with some value. Connected to this service by code above. But I have only one (last) value. Do you mean I must implement datalogger inside Movesense to get all values?

Comment: If your service start to log data when the service is connected then you should get all the logged data when reading the logbook from the phone side.

Comment: Please check exact question about it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57610986/datalogger-service-to-be-configured-to-subscribe-to-your-own-whiteboard-resource

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DataLogger can be started and stopped multiple times by PUT /Mem/DataLogger/State API. For detecting movement you can subscribe to [/System/States/0 (=MOVEMENT) api](https://bitbucket.org/suunto/movesense-device-lib/src/master/MovesenseCoreLib/resources/movesense-api/system/states.yaml) and start & stop recording based on the state change events (the recording will continue to the same log). This can be implemented on mobile as well as sensor code.

*Full Disclosure: I work for the Movesense team*